# How to connect JPARepository with ItemReader using spring batch?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I need to connect with jpa repository from ItemReader using spring batch for Database to text file export. But as of now i tried using JdbcCursorItemReader class to retrieve the data from db. I need to connect with Repository using spring data jpa.

Below is my code used

```
    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Object> databaseCsvItemReader(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<Object> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<Object>();
        reader.setSql(QUERY);
        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Object.class));
        return reader;

    }
```

From this reader i need to connect using Jpa instead of normal jdbc, anyone can help me on this or references it might help me to use jpa.

Answer (score 10):

> I need to connect with Repository using spring data jpa.

[RepositoryItemReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/data/RepositoryItemReader.html) is what you are looking for. It allows you to use a Spring Data repository to read items.

You can find examples of how to use it [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/data/RepositoryItemReaderTests.java).